# how to see the name of the user that banned someone?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def banchart(self,ctx):
    bannnedUsers = await ctx.guild.bans()
    for user in bannnedUsers:
        for i in range(len(user)):
            await ctx.send(user[i])
```

I'm trying to make a command where I can see what users are banned from a server and also who banned them.

But `ctx.guild.bans()` seems to only show the name of the banned user.

What else can I use to see the banned user and the person who banned them?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would become a little complex but let me go step by step. This might get a little confusing but

---

## Step By Step method to store who banned a member

#### Step 1: Creating a JSON File and add an empty dictionary in it.

The JSON file will be used to save the data into a JSON file as when the bot is rebooted the resources collected are deleted. So by adding this information to JSON file, we would save it permanently. We can add and extract data from JSON file and thus it would be of help here.

Create a file with any name. I am making: `moderationinfo.json`

Now add this code in it:

```
{
    "ban-mod": [
        
    ]
}
```

#### Step 2: Creating Ban command with addition of user data into the JSON file.

The command would ban a member as well as upload the information into the JSON file. We will then extract the data from the JSON file using another command I am going to explain below.

Ban Command:

```
@mybot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, kick_members=True, ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason):
    with open("moderationinfo.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
            
    all_users = []
    for user in data['ban-mod']:
        all_users.append(user['banned-member-id'])
    
    if member.id in all_users:
        for user in data['ban-mod']:
            if member.id == user['banned-member-id']:
                if user['moderator'] == str(ctx.author):
                    user['banned-member'] = str(member.name)
                    await member.ban(reason=reason)
                    await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} banned successfully by {ctx.author.name}!')

    else:
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} banned successfully by {ctx.author.name}')
        data["ban-mod"].append({"banned-member-id": member.id, "moderator": str(ctx.author), "banner-member": str(member.name)})

    with open("moderationinfo.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

I have considered the ID of the user that was banned as an important value as it is unique for everyone. So, the code first check if the entry exist or not. If it doesn't it creates a list and if it does then append values to it.

The values added up are: `banned-member-id`, `moderator`, `banned-member` and `time`.

More information can be taken from this answer:

[Discord.py: How to extract a Boolean value for if someone is muted or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968714/discord-py-how-to-extract-a-boolean-value-for-if-someone-is-muted-or-not)

I had asked this question for tempmute but the JSON work is the same. So you can take reference from it.

#### Step 3: Creating a `banchart` function to extract the values from the JSON file.

We will be creating a function and then extract the particular values and embed it in a message then print it. This command will display the data we want.

The BANCHART funtion:

```
@mybot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, kick_members=True, ban_members=True)
async def banchart(ctx):
    with open("moderationinfo.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    await ctx.channel.send(f'The banchart shows:')

    for user in data['ban-mod']:
        moderator = user['moderator']
        banned_member = user['banned-member']
        date = user['time']
        await ctx.channel.send(f"The moderator, **{moderator}** banned the user, **{banned_member}** on **{date}**")
```

This commands works just fine for what you want to do.

And this is all you have to do.

---

### Some images to explain these steps:

#### 1. Executing BAN Command and the Confirmation message.

[image: Command Execution and Result]

#### 2. BANCHART Command with our information.

[image: BANCHART Command with desired result]

#### 3. The Data in the JSON file.

[image: JSON File Data]

---

I hope that I was able to explain my working and please feel free to ask me any question if you still have any problem. :)

Thank You! :D

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch guild's audit log and search there for entries.