# Discord.py: How to extract a Boolean value for if someone is muted or not

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Recently, I have been working on my bot for a particular discord server. In the server I observed that if I closed the running script and then ran it again the previously inserted data was deleted and this is what I don't want to happen. It would lead to various bugs happening around.

The way my bot mutes someone is by assigning a role name: Muted. This role has the permissions of posting messages and joining VCs disabled. Thus, my bot gives this role when asked by a moderator.

I have a `tempmute` command which would mute someone for a particular time but if the bot shuts down then the timer is reset as well and the same would happen with many other things. Like there is a list into which I add members using a command. But as soon as the bot is restarted it is reset as well.

I want you to help me how to store data in a JSON file where I would insert the data for every single member. It following would be the things that I want to save:

- Name:
- Muted: True/False (I don't know this!)
- Banned: True/False (I don't know this!)
- Mute Time: (I am not sure with this!)
- Ban Time: (I am not sure with this!)
- Last Message:

The things which I have added notes are the ones I don't know. Please let me know how I can do what I want to do here. Any help would be appreciated.

The link to my code is: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/pogapiyolu.py

Thank You! :)

Comment: Do you count `time` with minutes?

Comment: What functionality do you want to achieve with `mute`? Should the command give them a "mute" role that takes away their ability to post messages or speak? Or should it just mute them when they join a voice channel?

Comment: @CaptAngryEyes The time is in `seconds`. :)

Comment: @CaptAngryEyes Also, here the `mute` does: 1. Can't send messages 2. Can't join a Voice Channel 3. Can't speak if already in a channel

My command gives the member a role named: `Muted` which doesn't allow member these things

Comment: Could you edit the post to include this information?

Comment: Oh sure. You have the answer I am seeking though?

Comment: “How do I do this”/“Implement this feature for me” is off-topic for StackOverflow, we help with specific programming questions. Another issue with this question is that you’re meant to add a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not your whole project (the code should also be posted within the question itself, not uploaded in some external sites)

Comment: You have shared your bot's token in your code. Make sure to regenerate it!

Comment: @CaptAngryEyes OH SHOOT!! Sorry and Thank You for mentioning it. I completely forgot that I shouldn't do that. Thanks again. And sure I would regenerate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your command we need to have some arguments. The info we need is: the user to be muted and the time the user will be muted for. As you requested I am going to go through the process of making a command to store the above info in a JSON file and give the user the "Muted" role. I am going to leave counting down and removing the "Muted" role up to you. The process is very similar.

So firstly create a JSON file in the same directory as your script. I named mine "mute.json". The file must contain the following:

```json
{
  "users": [
    
  ]
}
```

Then create the command, pass in the required arguments and load the JSON file.

```py
@bot.command()
async def tempmute(ctx, member : discord.Member, time : int):
    with open('mute.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

Now we need to check if the user is already in our JSON file. To do that we iterate through all the users already in the file and append their IDs to a list. Then we check if the user is in that list. If he is not in our file we add an object with his information to the "users" array.

```py
all_users = []
for user in data['users']:
        all_users.append(user['id'])
    
    if member.id in all_users:
else:
        data["users"].append({"id":member.id, "muted":True, "banned":False, "mute_time":time, "ban_time":0, "last_message": ""})
```

Note: I am using the user's ID to reference him. This way is better than using his name because, unlike the id, it can be changed.

Next, we need to check if the user in the file matches our specified user.

```py
 if member.id == user['id']:
```

Now we check if the user is already muted. If he isn't we mute him and define the time of the mute. This is the part where we are going to give the user the "Muted" role.

```py
if user['muted'] == False:
                    user['muted'] = True
                    user['mute_time'] = time
                    mute_role_id = member.guild.get_role(9999999999999999) # Change this to the "Muted" role ID
                    await member.add_roles(mute_role_id)
```

And now that we have made the changes to the JSON file and given the role to the user we must save the changes.

```py
with open('mute.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

So the final complete command looks like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def tempmute(ctx, member : discord.Member, time : int):
    with open('mute.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
            
    all_users = []
    for user in data['users']:
        all_users.append(user['id'])
    
    if member.id in all_users:
        for user in data['users']:
            if member.id == user['id']:
                if user['muted'] == False:
                    user['muted'] = True
                    user['mute_time'] = time
                    mute_role_id = member.guild.get_role(9999999999999999)
                    await member.add_roles(mute_role_id)
    else:
        mute_role_id = member.guild.get_role(9999999999999999)
        await member.add_roles(mute_role_id)
        data["users"].append({"id":member.id, "muted":True, "banned":False, "mute_time":time, "ban_time":0, "last_message": ""})

    with open('mute.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

You can modify and tweak values to make this a "ban" command as well.
I hope I could help!

Comment: I tried this code. But when I executed it nothing happened.

Comment: That is the problem. No Errors. It just do nothing.

Comment: Use this code. This is the command I created: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/pepenegebe.py

Comment: Add a "print" statement in the first "for" loop and print "all_users". What does it say?

Comment: Oh just a second.

Comment: Nothing happen. Nothing is printed.

Comment: Also, how do you "pass in" time? For example, how does the discord command look like in chat?

Comment: The command entered to exceute: `!tempmute @user#1111 1h Reason`
Then I extract the value at index 0 of `1h` and multiply it with the time conversion dictionary. Thus getting the time in seconds.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add `json.dump()` to your code. That is why the data isn't being saved to the file. I state that you have to add these lines of code in my answer above. Also a little mistake I made; `all_users = []` must be outside the first "for" loop. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Oops! I made that dumb move. I would add the `json.dump()` now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230838/discussion-between-captangryeyes-and-bhavyadeep-yadav).

Comment: No! Your help really worked out. The JSON file has that information that I need and also that `all_users` list repaired. I added `dump` and now, FINNALY THIS WORKS! You are really great my friend. Thank You very much! :D I accept this answer. :)